# BitDefender opens randomly

Tags: macos, anti-virus

BitDefender's Dock icon pops up randomly and I have to quit again and again. I tried to contact the support but got only some generic response. Does anyone have the same problem and have a workaround?

Here is the example of the icon appearing after closing iPhoto:

[image]

Comment: I tested some antivirus and best of all by far, was [Avast](http://www.avast.com/en-us/index). By the way, it was also the lightest.

Comment: If you make your question very specific we can take it off Hold.

Comment: A useful reference on the general issue is  http://www.reedcorner.net/mmg/

Comment: I made the title more specific, I hope this is ok

Comment: I've tried to make your question more specific to the problem at hand (and voted to re-open).

Comment: I voted to get it off hold but needs more votes :(

Comment: Not a big problem because I already removed BD and got Avast as @jherran suggested... so far so great